# RxJS: Count changes on collection items

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Given a collection of items, what is the best way to track/monitor/count changes in a specific time interval on any item/itemProperty?
More specific, I need to be able to monitor changes and notify on specific dynamic conditions.

My solution so far:
Every time something changes, I push a data change log in a ReplaySubject.
I subscribe to this subject and apply some custom operators which filter on a specific column and count changes.

Ex. 'notify me if property X of item Y was changed 2 times in the last 5 seconds'

```js
// const dataChangeLog$ = new ReplaySubject(...)

    dataChangeLog$.pipe(
      filterColumnChanges('columnName'), // filters only changes on the given column
      windowTime(5000),
      switchMap((change$) => change$.pipe(countCellChanges(2)))
    );

    const countCellChanges = (
      limit: number,
      reset = true
    ): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<DataChangedLogEntry> => {
      return (source$) =>
        defer(() => {
          const counterMap = new Map<unknown, number>();

          const getCellCounter = (dataChangeLog: DataChangedLogEntry) =>
            counterMap.get(dataChangeLog.primaryKeyValue) ?? 0;

          return source$.pipe(
            tap((dataChangeLog) => {
              let currentCounter = getCellCounter(dataChangeLog);
              counterMap.set(dataChangeLog.primaryKeyValue, ++currentCounter);
            }),
            filter((dataChangeLog) => {
              return getCellCounter(dataChangeLog) >= limit;
            }),
            // if limit is reached, reset it
            tap((dataChangeLog) => {
              if (reset) {
                counterMap.set(dataChangeLog.primaryKeyValue, 0);
              }
            })
          );
        });
    };
```

The problem is that the counter is reset every 5 seconds, regardless of how many changes I have in this interval.
What I really need is to check on every emission if there were at least X emissions in the last Y seconds.

Comment: Have a look at the `bufferTime` operator, see if it will do the trick for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This operator checks the source and emits as soon as
the condition you describe is satisfied.

```js
const xInLastY = (x, y) => (source$) => {
  const runningCount$ = source$.pipe(
    mergeMap(() => {
      const inc$ = of(1);
      const dec$ = of(-1).pipe(delay(y));
      return of(inc$, dec$).pipe(mergeAll());
    }),
    scan((acc, next) => acc + next, 0),
  );

  return runningCount$.pipe(
    map((count) => count >= x),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    filter(x => x)
  );
};
```

EDIT: Addressing this bit specifically:

> notify me if property X of item Y was changed 2 times in the last 5 seconds

The operator slots in neatly to this use case.

```js
const recentChangesToProperty$ = source$.pipe(
  distinctUntilKeyChanged(MY_PROPERTY),
  xInLastY(2, 5e3)
);
```

**Last update:**

This generalizes the "condition over last X ms" case to satisfy OP's other requirement:

> emit only if changed value is the highest/lowest in the last x milliseconds

Instead of accumulating a growing/shrinking count, we accumulate a growing/shrinking array of the values. The "max" case is implemented below, and the "min" implementation follows pretty easily from this.

```js
type ArrayAction<T> = { type: 'PUSH'; value: T } | { type: 'POP' };

const arrayReducer = <T>(state: T[], action: ArrayAction<T>) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'PUSH':
      return [...state, action.value];
    case 'POP':
      return state.slice(1);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const timeTrailingValues = (ms: number) => <T>(
  source$: Observable<T>
): Observable<T[]> => {
  const runningList$ = source$.pipe(
    mergeMap((value) => {
      const in$ = of({ type: 'PUSH', value });
      const out$ = of({ type: 'POP' }).pipe(delay(y));
      return of(in$, out$).pipe(mergeAll());
    }),
    scan(arrayReducer, [])
  );
};

const maxInLastX = (ms: number) => <T>(
  source: Observable<T>
): Observable<boolean> =>
  source$.pipe(
    timeTrailingValues(ms),
    map((xs) => {
      const [latestValue] = xs.slice(-1);
      const rest = xs.slice(0, -1);
      return rest.every((value) => value <= latestValue);
    }),
    filter(isMax => isMax)
  );

// Still want to track the running count? Combine timeTrailingValues with this
const atSize = (x: number) => <T>(
  source$: Observable<T[]>
): Observable<boolean> => {
  return source$.pipe(
    map((xs) => xs.length >= x),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    filter((x) => x)
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I'm not at the working station right now so I can't play with it but, correct me if I read it wrong, this operator will wait for Y milliseconds and then will emit TRUE if there were at least X emissions in this time.  

What I need is to emit right away if there are at least X emissions in the last at most Y milliseconds.
Sorry, now i realize that my question wasn't clear.

Comment: No, it should work as you want it. Think of it this way - we're creating an intermediate observable `delta$` which emits only 1 and -1. For each emission from the source, it emits 1 immediately, and then emits -1 after Y milliseconds. By summing up these 1s and -1s (using `scan`), we get a continuously up-to-date count of emissions in the last Y milliseconds.

Comment: I updated the resulting observable to emit right away when the condition is satisfied (it was emitting continuous true/false values).

Comment: Thanks, now I understand it :)  
Obviously your rxjs is much much advanced than mine, do you have some hints for my use case? I have a list (not a stream) and every change on it is pushed in a changeLog stream (a ReplaySubject).  
I want to be able to build dynamic queries and extract informations from the changeLog like:  
1. this item/property was changed,  
2. this item/property was changed X times,  
3. this item/property was changed X times in the last Y seconds,  
4. this property was changed to it's min/max value  [in the last Y seconds] etc

Comment: Until now (with your help) I was able to map most of these queries to some custom rxjs operators, but almost every query has it's own implementation.  
Do you have some hints on how to deconstruct these queries to some base building blocks(operators) that can be afterwards composed to some complex queries?

Comment: Sure, it sounds pretty composable. Going by your numbered list: 1. `distinctUntilKeyChanged(someProperty)`. 2. `scan((acc) => acc + 1, 0)` or `map((_x, i) => i)` gives you a running count of emits. combine with #1. 3. see the main answer; it's #1 combined with `xInLastY`. 4. `filter(x => x === MIN || x === MAX)`, combine with #1.

Comment: Also if you're happy with my answer, feel free to upvote as well :)

Comment: I did, but I don't have enough reputation points ;)

Comment: This is a bit embarrassing, but I didn't manage to combine your solution with aggregation functions like MIN,MAX (emit only if changed value is the highest/lowest in the last x milliseconds).
As before, I'm having problems with the moving time window...

Comment: Highest/lowest compared to what? You mentioned 'its min/max value' in another comment, but we could also be talking about highest/lowest compared to the other values emitted in the last X ms. Like: newest value is 5, other values emitted in the time window are [2, 6, 1], so we don't emit. Is that the intention?

Comment: "highest/lowest compared to the other values emitted in the last X ms": that's exactly what I mean.  
When a value is greater/lower than all the values emitted in the last X ms, than it is considered as a new MAX/MIN.  
(Of course, if no limiting time interval is given I will compare the new value against all values)

Comment: Updated! If you need further help, I suggest opening a new question so this one doesn't grow too large.

Comment: Ooh actually there's a mistake in the `in$`/`out$` bit. I'll fix it when I can.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With some adjustments/extensions I managed to do everything I needed :)